# Apache URL rewrite to ajax url with query string

Tags: ajax, apache, url-rewriting, http-redirect, url-rewrite-module

I have a requirement for URL rewrite, below is the example URL and it is ajax call will invoke the click event

**From**
 `https://www.test.com/load/research/compare?submit=true&Actions=ajax&componentID=1600176192830&alias=test-with-machine&subFeature=%2Ftemplate%2Fcontent%2Fmedia`

**To**

`https://www.test.com/learn/research/detail?submit=true&Actions=ajax&componentID=1600176192830&alias=test-with-machine&subFeature=%2Ftemplate%2Fcontent%2Fmedia`

I tried multiple ways to handle this but all failed, below is the VHOST entry

```
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)submit=true(.*)$
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)submit=([^&]*)(&|$)
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^(.*&)?submit=true?(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
    RewriteRule ^/load/research/^(.*)/$           http://localhost:8080/learn/research/detail? [QSA]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following URL rewrites working fine

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?submit=true?(&.*)?$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/load/research/(.*)$    http://localhost:8080/learn/research/detail?submit=true%1%2 [P,L]
```